# Ice, [ice], baby?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I submitted an excerpt for [ice](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice), but I realized that not all the existing questions were about extra-terrestrial ice (e.g. [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16715/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5854/12102)). Trying to shove rocket ice into that mix introduces double meanings, which, on SO, is a huge no-no (rocket ice != Martian ice).

Should we make [rocket-ice] or just leave it alone?

Comment: I made an edit; all → not all. Check if that's what you meant or not.

Answer (score 2):

I skipped approving it for this reason. I'd suggest removing ice from questions where it's about icing.

Would ice forming on a cryogenic return stage on a different planet count?

What about the ice observed by the Apollo crew after performing their ablutions?